# CSS automatically loaded during running of hot towel angular js SPA application with bootstrap. Couldn't find how?

Tags: c#, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2012

CSS files are automatically get loaded everytime from the tfs location when i run the angular js SPA application in Visual Studio. So locally made changes to the css are not effective and lost. How to fix this problem. I am using hot towel angular js single page frame work including bootstrap.

Getting the below message everytime i run the application.

```
This file has been modified outside of the source editor. Do you want to reload it?
```

kindly help me.

Comment: Check where you file loading from? Have tried after clearing your cache?

Comment: Is it browser cache or visual studio cache? How to remove that?

Answer (score 0):

This is the Browser Link feature in visual studio. Just to the left of the Debug tool there is an arrow-circle drop-down. Click on that and un-select Enable Browser Link.

Comment: I couldn't find any arrow-circle left to the debug tool in my visual studio 2012. Kindly help.How can i check that?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer :)

I am using Grunt to compile and minify my css files during my builds. That was the problem.

While Grunt is running, it will compile your stylesheets every time you commit changes to one of your LESS files.  After i comment the particular css file from building via grunt it works fine.

http://ericnish.io/blog/compile-less-files-with-grunt.